# Testing Views in Rspec , undefined method collect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I got this following error while i am testing views in Rspec.

1) problems/new renders new problem form

```
Failure/Error: 
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
  <%= f.select :approval_status, options_for_select(@approval_statuses.collect { |as| [as[0].humanize, as[0]] }, selected: @problem.approval_status), {}, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
ActionView::Template::Error:
  undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass
```

I am passing @approval_statuses in controller action.
It's working fine in views , but in test cases i am getting this error.

Controller Action :

```
def new
   @problem = Problem.new
   @approval_statuses = Problem.approval_statuses
   @visibilities = Problem.visibilities
end
```

In Model

```
enum approval_status: {not_approved: 0, approved: 1}
```

In new.html.erb_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "problems/new", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
  assign(:problem, Problem.new())
  end

  it "renders new problem form" do
   render
   assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", problems_path, "post" do
   end

  end
end
```

Comment: @approval_statuses is nil, please paste your controller action.

Comment: @JuanManuelRodulfoSalcedo : added controller action.

Comment: I suppose Problem.approval_statuses is method returning some data from the DB so i suppose you don't have those seeds in test environment.

Comment: did you do prepare database for `test` I mean is the `problems` table present in the test database

Comment: I am generating the data with FactoryGirl . Dono actually what is test database. Is that the data in seeds.rb @RajarshiDas

Comment: no factory girl will create the data in your test database you need to prepare the using `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` or rake db:test:prepare

Comment: ya i am using sqlite3 as my test database. But still i get this same error . @RajarshiDas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `@problem` instance variable but not `@approval_statuses` or `@visibilities` so these are both currently nil.

```
RSpec.describe "problems/new", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:problem, Problem.new)
    assign(:approval_statuses, Problem.approval_statues)
    assign(:visibilities, Problem.visibilities)
  end

  it "renders new problem form" do
    render

    assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", problems_path, "post" do
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, This solution solved my problem and i realized what i was missing.